# How to conditionally trigger a JSON statement or display image

Tags: json-formatting, json

Team,

I am using the SharePoint conditional formatting (bottom) to display a PDF icon in lieu of a URL link to a PDF (I run a Power Automate flow to create a PDF copy of each file uploaded to SharePoint, and I want to display an image link to the PDF copy).

The JSON below works well, except it also generates icons for sub-folders in the document library.

I need help to tweak the JSON below so that when **@currentField** is blank, the JSON is not run, or it suppresses the "children" properties.

If I simply place an IF statement in the SRC value, for example...

*"src": "=if(@currentField = '', '', '../../SiteAssets/PDF_icon_32x32.png')"*

It will display PDF icons for the files, but displays an empty image icon for the folders, rather than nothing at all.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "[$PDFlink]"
  },
  "style": {
    "text-decoration": "none"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "img",
      "style": {
        "display": "block",
        "position": "relative",
        "width": "32px",
        "height": "32px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "src": "../../SiteAssets/PDF_icon_32x32.png"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to use the ? operator to encapsulate the children parameters into an if/then block?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I found the answer here -> [https://tomriha.com/hide-json-built-hyperlink-in-sharepoint-...](https://tomriha.com/hide-json-built-hyperlink-in-sharepoint-list-if-theres-no-underlying-link/)

I changed the display value from "block" to include an **if statement**, so that if the **@currentField** is empty **then** display = **none**, **else** display = **block**.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-fo...",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "@currentField"
  },
  "style": {
    "text-decoration": "none"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "img",
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(@currentField == '','none','block')",
        "position": "relative",
        "width": "32px",
        "height": "32px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "src": "../../SiteAssets/PDF_icon_32x32.png"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Regards
Michael